# SavePreferences only saving last item in ListView

Tags: android, listview, adapter

I was trying to use Save/Load Preferences to save the User's input through EditView. However, my current code only saves the last string the user inputted. So when i re-enter the app, the only string in the ListView is the last string the user entered.

How can i fix this?

EDITED CODE BELOW:

```
addButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String task = display.getText().toString();


                adapter.add(task);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                JSONArray array = new JSONArray();
                array.add(task);


                SavePreferences("LISTS", array.toString());
        }
    });
}

protected void SavePreferences(String key, String value) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    SharedPreferences data = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = data.edit();
    editor.putString("LISTS", value);
    editor.commit();


}

protected void LoadPreferences(){
    SharedPreferences data = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    String dataSet = data.getString("LISTS", "");


    adapter.add(dataSet);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    ArrayList<String> dataSetarrlist = new ArrayList<String>();
    dataSetarrlist.add(dataSet);
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, 
                         android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice,dataSetarrlist);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: Check my updated answer below, with an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aren't you overwriting the same key?

```
SavePreferences("LISTS", task);
```

in
    editor.putString(key, value);

It will always write on key "LISTS" of the SharedPreferences, overwriting the previous value.

You should try to get the current saved values to a string and append the new value.

Sort of:

```
String dataset = loadPreferences();
SavePreferences("LISTS",dataset+task);
```

Depending on the desired save format.

-- Example --

```
protected void SavePreferences(String key, String value) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
   SharedPreferences data = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
   JSONArray array = new JSONArray(data.getString(key,"");
   SharedPreferences.Editor editor = data.edit();
   editor.putString(key, value);
   editor.commit();
}


protected void LoadPreferences(){
   SharedPreferences data = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
   JSONArray dataSet = new JSONArray(data.getString("LISTS", "None Available");)
   for(int i = 0; i<dataSet.length; i++)
     adapter.add(dataSet.getString(i);
   adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); // You don't need this if you aren't overriding the Adapters 'add' method.
}
```

Comment: I am still kind of confused as to where I have to fix this. I understand that my key, "LISTS" is always going to be written on so it takes away the last value. How would i make it so that it goes in different keys so it doesnt overwrite the previous value

Comment: I think the best way to do what you want is to use somekind of structure. You can still save in the samekey, but create an Array (eg. JSONArray) with all the values.

Lets make a simple example. We are using key = toast;

JSONArray array = new JSONArray(preferences.getString(Toast));
array.add(task)
savePreferenceS("list",array.toString);

This basically creates a JSONArray (eg. [1,2,3,4]) and converts this to a string "[1,2,3,4]" and saves in sharedpreferences. Then you just loadup that string again, recreate the jsonarray and "add" the new element.

Comment: I tried this method but i think i am doing it wrong. Is the JSONArray supposed to be used in place of an Adapter or is it just created in the onClick method so that the user input is saved to the JSON ARray and then to SavePreferences

Comment: Just created in the onClick method. Jsut for "adding new item"

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are writing on the same key "LISTS" and it will take always the last value. You should use different keys or just get the previous value from "LISTS" key, add a separator character and append the new preferences. Then in your LoadPReferences use String.split(pattern) to get all the values.